# fontawesome: can not change color of stacked icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Here is the plunker - http://plunker.co/edit/npLOW06U0aAVZmGAHv7U?p=preview

In `style.css`, I do

```
.icon-stack .icon-sign-blank: {
 color: red; 
}
.icon-stack .icon-trash: {
  color: white;
}
```

but it does not changes color, what is that I am doing incorrect here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does change colour, but you have unnecessary colons `:` after both selectors, simply remove them:

```
.icon-stack .icon-sign-blank {
color: red; 
 }

.icon-stack .icon-trash {
 color: white;
 }
```

http://plunker.co/edit/6z6bMO1opw6zyxAz4DN4?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

just declare a separate class e.g

```
.red{
 color:red;
}
```

and include it when calling the icon class i.e

```
<i class="icon-stack red"></i>
```